# Invalid jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

Why is the dialog only draggable within the viewpoint? A simple div element may be draggable outside the viewpoint (please see the picture at savepic.net/187084.jpg); what I am looking for is to make the dialog draggable outside the viewpoint too. What is the option to provide? Please consider the code at http://jsfiddle.net/MwXKE/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [`containment` is `document`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.6/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L407) for the dialog's [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment), you can turn it off though, like this:

```
$('<p>Dialog</p>').dialog().parent().draggable("option", { containment: false });
```

[You can test it with your demo code here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/MwXKE/1/).  We turn it off on the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) because the dialog gets wrapped in a parent (that includes the title bar, etc), and *that's* the element that's draggable.